# format dropdownlist control have two columns

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to fill data into select control like:

> abc           ||    1 
>  
>   bcde        ||    2 
>  
>   ghife       ||    3

And my code

```
ArrayList arr = new CMProduct().getList();
        string str = "<option value='0'>" + strApp + "</option>";
        if (arr != null)
        {
            foreach (MProductInfo info in arr)
            {
                string select = "";
                string sName = "";
                if (info.ID == id_select)
                    select = "selected";
                //int length = 80;
                int fLengthString = info.Name.Length;
                int iPadRight = 0; iPadRight = 100 - fLengthString;
                sName = info.Name.PadRight(iPadRight, '\u00a0');
                str += "<option " + select + " value='" + info.ID + "'>" + sName + info.Code + "</option>";
            }
        }
        return str;
```

Ressult:

> abc       ||    1 
>  
>   bcde       ||    2 
>  
>   ghife       ||    3

So how to fix it?

Comment: use fixed-width font and space padding for the dropdown?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font